# Alterando um campo com uma respectiva cor e retornando pro banco

Tags: formulário, input, cors

estou com uma duvida nao seu por onde começar Tenho um projeto que presisa de um calendário de horario na qual esse calendario tem uma tabela com varios quadrado e presiso alterar a cor desse quadrados com algumas cores correspondente a um status e presiso devolver esse status de volta pro banco alterado eu pensei em fazer onde o usuario clica no quadrado abre uma palheta de cor com a alteraçao da cor e cada cor e relacionada a um status mas nao sei como começar

o calendario é igual a imagem a baixo ele esta em excel quero trasformar isso ai em codigo para web [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bruno, é possível fazer usando eventos de click e requisições ajax. Dica estude mais sobre Jquery, a biblioteca faz tudo isso e mais um pouco.

Comment: mas eu consigo usar esse evento em cima de uma tabela pq eu fiz um com <th> e <td> mas nao deu muito certo